# SQL Server auto-delete FK records based on combined key from two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a table to store notes about any record in any data table in the db and have the note record deleted when the related data record is deleted.

Can I set up a combined FK key relationship between the note table, table-id table and data tables and use an ON DELETE CASCADE or do I need to use ON DELETE triggers on the data tables, or what would be the best approach?

E.g. with three tables, FRUITS, BUILDINGS, CLOTHES;

```
FRUITS_ID   NAME    |     BUILDINGS_ID  TEXT     |    CLOTHES_ID    TYPE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           APPLE   |     1             HOUSE    |    1             COAT
2           LEMON   |     2             HOSPITAL |    2             BOOTS
3           PLUM    |     3             PRISON   |
```

I define a table of table ids;

```
REFTABLE_ID     TABLENAME
-------------------------                   
21              FRUITS                      
22              BUILDINGS                       
23              CLOTHES
```

and the notes table uses the table id and record id within that table;

```
NOTES_ID    REFTABLE_ID  REFTABLE_RECORD_ID  NOTETEXT       
-------------------------------------------------------------   
1           21           1                   Make a pie             
2           21           2                   Try lemonade               
3           22           2                   Handles emergencies                
4           23           1                   Can be waterproof
```

So the notetext for record 'HOSPITAL' (BUILDINGS_ID 2) in BUILDINGS (REFTABLE_ID 22) is 'Handles emergencies' (NOTES_ID 3)

What is the best approach to 'automatically' delete note record id 3 when BUILDINGS record id 2 is deleted?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot think of any way to use FK from  your note table to the data tables in your model. But I would seriously consider remodelling this. Either by having a note table for each data table or by merging the three data tables to one and add a category table for separating fruits/buildings and clothes.

Comment: Thanks but these tables are just a very simplified example. My db is a long-running production one so I am restricted to what major structural changes I can make. We need to make 'notes' on different records in different tables and I don't want to add a 'note' column to each table because very few notes will actually be created.

Comment: That makes sense. You could, of course, still create separate note tables for each of the data tables for which you need notes - without having to add a notes column to the data tables, but reference the data table id from the notes table. But I agree that this would seem like an overkill if few notes will be created.

Comment: Sure, but I think it would be overkill, yes. We already have the table of table-ids which is used for other things so it seems the simplest approach is to add a notes table as described above. I just want to ensure referential integrity for this new table. Open to other suggestions though! Thanks

Comment: I cannot think of any ways to set up a FK on the reftable_record_id column in your example, I believe it simply cannot be done. And therefore you cannot enforce referential integrity by keys alone. I have no other suggestions than implementing delete triggers, as you have suggested, on the data tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server 2008 or above I think you can use MERGE statement.
Also if you add additional columns "TABLE_ID" to your all your three tables FRUITS, BUILDINGS and CLOTHES then I think you could do it like below (Assuming the name of your table with Table Ids is "TABLE_IDS"):

```
MERGE NOTES AS Target
USING (SELECT TBL.REFTABLE_ID, B.BUILDINGS_ID, F.FRUITS_ID, C.CLOTHES_ID 
FROM 
BUILDINGS [B] JOIN TABLE_IDS [TBL] ON B.TABLE_ID=TBL.TABLE_ID JOIN FRUITS [F] 
ON F.TABLE_ID=TBL.TABLE_ID JOIN CLOTHES [C] ON C.TABLE_ID=TBL.TABLE_ID) 
As Source
ON ((Target.REFTABLE_RECORD_ID = Source.BUILDINGS_ID  AND Target.REFTABLE_ID 
= Source.REFTABLE_ID) 
OR (Target.REFTABLE_RECORD_ID =Source.FRUITS_ID AND Target.REFTABLE_ID = 
Source.REFTABLE_ID) 
OR (Target.REFTABLE_RECORD_ID =Source.CLOTHES_ID AND Target.REFTABLE_ID = 
Source.REFTABLE_ID))
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN DELETE
OUTPUT Deleted.*;
```